# Github workflow ECR deployment on non-master branch

Tags: git, github, git-workflow

I have a workflow where I build a docker image and deploy to ECR. However, there is a syntax issue with the following part.

```
on:
  release:
    types:
    - [published, edited]
    branches:
        - production/*
```

I am assuming this is because of the branches part in this file. However I really need the deployment to be carried out only in the event of a release from the production branch. (We will not make releases from the master). If I remove the branches section would it still trigger for releases I make from the production branch?
I have checked the documentation [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows), but it does not mention a specific branch tag. How can this be managed?

Answer (score 0):

This was just  a syntax issue with the spacing in the branches section. This works perfectly as I wanted

```
on:
  release:
    types: [published, edited]
    branches:
    - production/*
```